# Sliding Tile Board Game--Lingo Bingo?

Tags: identify-this-game

I'm looking for a board game that was one of my mother's favorites growing up. This would have been in the early to mid 70's.

It was a game for four people, each with a 4x4 (with one empty) sliding tile setup with letters. A paper wheel in the middle of the board could be turned and would reveal four words for each player, and the players would race to spell those words with their sliding tiles.

She thought the name of this game was Lingo Bingo, but I can't seem to find even a mention of a board game with that name anywhere. Does it sound familiar to anyone? Is there a place where I can buy it?

Comment: Since it might help us narrow down our searching: what year or decade would your mother have had this?

Comment: This would have been early to mid-70's.

Comment: Good idea. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to find a *partial* match for what you're describing. It isn't your exact game, but I'm posting it hoping it'll help someone *find* that game — it sounds like a possible ancestor or derivative.

The former [**Ideal Toy Company**](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamepublisher/153/ideal) produced [**Logus Sr.**](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/9592/logus-sr) and [**Logus Jr.**](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/23971/logus-jr) in 1971. This is a 2-player game that gives the players a **4×5** grid of letters, two spaces missing, making for 18 letter tiles. You're assigned challenges of various formats by cards. There's no wheel and there's no 4-player.

[image: Logus Sr, two 4x5 tile cases with their cards in a box] 
[image: logus jr, same again, in the box]
<sup>First: Logus Sr. Image credit: [Bagherra on Board Game Geek](https://boardgamegeek.com/image/39916/logus-sr). // Second: Logus Jr. Image credit: [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EB9349U)</sup>

(Logus found thanks to [Graham Toal, Steffan O'Sullivan, and the wordgame-programmers mailing list](http://www.gtoal.com/wordgames/games.html).)

Comment: That's definitely close, and I agree that it might be from the same game lineage. It's as if the one I'm talking about has evaporated, and I've seen the game myself (my mother still had it when I was a kid, but has since misplaced it), so I know she's not just mis-remembering the mechanics of it.